# Progress Dialog not appearing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, progressdialog

I have a `ListView` in `Activity1`. `OnItemClick`, I'm navigating to another activity  `Activity2` where I have some database code.

Now the problem is fetching data from DB is taking some time, so while navigating from  `Activity1` to  `Activity2`, for few seconds blank screen appears.

To overcome this, I tried `ProgressDialog` but `ProgressDialog` is not appearing at all.

**Code snippet from Activity 2:**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity implements Runnable {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Thread thread = new Thread();
        thread.start();
        run();
}
```

---

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        plansDesc = dbMgr.chkRecord(
                "SELECT Description FROM SubPlan where Title='" + subTitle
                        + "'", "Description");

        ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(
                SubPlanDescActivity.this, "Plan Information", "Loading...",
                true);
        try {
            if (plansDesc != "") {
                tvDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(plansDesc));
            } else {
                tvDesc.setText(Html
                        .fromHtml("<b>No Information Available...</b>"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        progDailog.dismiss();
    }

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    }
};
```

*ANY HELP APPRECIATED.*

Comment: since you are implementing runnable,so remove run(); under thread.start();

Comment: You are right. But id I don't call run manually, it is not getting executed...

Comment: Check my answer, to use your run method, you have to pass your runnable object as an argument of the Thread object.

Comment: Use [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).. that solves your problem..

Comment: i have made changes in the code.pls kindly try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try AsyncTask instead of thread

See the below code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   new ProgressTask().execute();
}
```

Now create class

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

  private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

  protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    this.dialog.show();
  }

  protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
    try {

        plansDesc = dbMgr.chkRecord(
            "SELECT Description FROM SubPlan where Title='" + subTitle
                    + "'", "Description");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", "error", e);
        return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (success) {
        // display UI
        if (plansDesc != "") {
            tvDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(plansDesc));
        } else {
            tvDesc.setText(Html
                    .fromHtml("<b>No Information Available...</b>"));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to dismiss the Progress Dialog inside the Handler.

```
   private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        progDailog.dismiss();
        }
    };
```

Try modifying the code like this,

```
@Override
public void run() {
     handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    plansDesc = dbMgr.chkRecord(
            "SELECT Description FROM SubPlan where Title='" + subTitle
                    + "'", "Description");


    try {
        if (plansDesc != "") {
            tvDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(plansDesc));
        } else {
            tvDesc.setText(Html
                    .fromHtml("<b>No Information Available...</b>"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

}
```

And your handler like this,

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      if(msg.what==0)
            {
             progDailog.dismiss();
               }
      if(msg.what==1)
      {
          ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(
            SubPlanDescActivity.this, "Plan Information", "Loading...",
            true);
         }

    }
};
```

Comment: If it still doesn't help, remove handler.sendEmptyMessage(1); from run() and add it to onCreate() before you start the Thread.

Comment: I tried you edited answer, now progress bar is appearing but it is not getting dismissed.

Comment: are you sure. can you check whether you have placed handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);. You could have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

write this:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity implements Runnable {
Thread thread;
ProgressDialog dialog;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(yourLayout);


dialog=ProgressDialog.show(this, "","Loading...",true);
dialog.show();
thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();

}

public void run() {
        plansDesc = dbMgr.chkRecord(
            "SELECT Description FROM SubPlan where Title='" + subTitle
                    + "'", "Description");


    try {
        if (plansDesc != "") {
            tvDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(plansDesc));
        } else {
            tvDesc.setText(Html
                    .fromHtml("<b>No Information Available...</b>"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);        
    }



 private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()){
                 dialog.dismiss();
                 }
        }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want load data then use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) It's best solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate method, you have to put your "Runnable" element (here "this") as a thread object parameter. And then, you don't need to call your "run" method, it will call automatically with the start() method from the Thread object.

code example :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
```

I'm not sure, this solves your problem entirely, but this is the good way to use a Thread with a Runnable Interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>() {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showProgress...
        }

        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... structs) {
            Loading data...

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            Hide progress...

        }

    }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the progress dialog in the Activity, not in the database thread. Use Handler to send a message from the thread when it's done and hide the dialog.